# Django json field to form fields

Tags: python, django, web

I have a django app that into the model has a json field looks like this

```
from json_field import JSONField
from django.db import models 

class C(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    jf   = JSONField(null=False)
```

There is a form that display this as follow

```
 class Edit(forms.Form):
     name      = forms.CharField()
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         if 'extra' in kwargs:
             extra = kwargs.pop('extra')
             super(Edit, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
             for k, v in extra.iteritems():
                  self.fields['%s' % k] = v
         else:
             super(Edit, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The view will load the json field jf and send it to the Form as initial data, as well
will send all the necessary fields as extra.

```
def edit_model(request, pk):
    obj = get_object_or_404(models.C, pk=pk)
    initial = model_to_dict(obj)
    form = Edit(request.POST or None, initial=initial, extra=initial['jf'])
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            .....
            # what is the best practice here ?
            # intersect cleaned data with the jf fields ?!
            # have an external entity that does this ?!
            # is anything built into django that can help
```

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you can try [this custom widget's form of django](https://github.com/abbasovalex/django-SplitJSONWidget-form) It does JSON to formfields and formfields -> JSON after save

Comment: I'll give it a try - from a first look its' promising - thanks!